# Iphone audio route selection button

Tags: iphone, audio, view

I have seen that the voice memos app has a button that shows the audio route selection menu.
How can I add such a button (or display the route selection from code). I tried using `MPVolumeView` but it only shows the button sometimes, I would like to always display the button (and to not include the volume bar)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Managed to add it with following:

```
MPVolumeView *volumeView = [MPVolumeView new]
volumeView.showsVolumeSlider = NO;
volumeView.showsRouteButton = YES;
[volumeView sizeToFit];
```